# An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command

Tags: symfony

```
[RuntimeException]                                                         
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

i like to upgrade my symfony2.0 project to symfony 2.3 .

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/v2.3.1/UPGRADE.md

i followed above one to upgrade my project .But i'm facing following errors

```
[RuntimeException]                                                         
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

Comment: are you using such command as admin/root etc?

Comment: try to delete `app/cache/*`

Comment: hey @kovarthan could you solve your problem? I have the same one using capifony and of course composer

Comment: if one of these answers worked for you, you should really accept it

Answer (score 12):

run `sudo php composer.phar update --no-scripts`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. I tried to run

```
php app/console
```

and got another error. I fixed this error and afterwards I could update without this unspecific error.

Comment: Worked for me also. An existing php error in one of my files was blocking the installation. Nice work @Manuel